# GNU linker no success to make a relocatable module with calls to absolute addresses

Tags: linker, gnu, absolute, relocation

I work on a MC68360 platform using GNU development tools.

What I need is a relocatable execution module that can make calls to absolute addresses,
i.e to functions that are already in memory (ROM).

I can't get the GNU linker to do so.
The place of the function call in the application is a relocatable address
and the provided function address is an absolute address.
The end result is a relocatable address.

How did I do it so far:
I extract the Global Functions from the rom-image and make a file out of this, say **rom_functions.S**. This file looks like this:

```
    .text
    
    .globl sqrt
    .equ    sqrt, 0x<abs addr>
```

A check with readelf on **rom_functions.o** confirms all symbols are absolute addresses, there is no relocation table either.

**rom_functions.o**  is used to link with the application into a relocatable module with the following command line:

```
ld -d -r -Rrom_functions.o -uappl_start -Tmyscript @$objs -o appl.rel appl.o
```

The -R is used to include and preserve absolute addresses as is the purpose of this option I guess. Possibly I have mis-interpreted the -R option. I have tried -R<rom.img> but yields similar result , the called function address is made relocatable in the output and is thus - when loading - modified with the loadaddress; eventulally a the call will nog enter the desired function.

Is there a solution to achieve what I want: a relocatable module with calls to absolute addresses?

Comment: I have seen an answer suggesting to specify in the script .text section  the symbol and its absolute address and then  linking with the -Ur option.  That is no success either, the output specifies still relocation for those addresses that make a reference to the absolute symbol.

Comment: I have a conversion program to prepare the relocation module into a binary load file: 
a) sectors of 512 bytes and b) each sector comprises code and a relocation bitrow.
I may consider to enhance the conversion program by removing relocation for locations  that are referring to absolute symbols.